# BeautifulSoup finds an html element that contains spaces in its attributes

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How to use `BeautifulSoup` to find an *html* element that contains *spaces* in its attributes

```html
<h1 class='td p1'>
    title that i want
</h1>
<h1 class='td p2'>
    title that i don't want
</h1>
<h1 class='p1'>
    title that i don't want
</h1>
```

I would like to know how to use `soup.find` to find the `title that i want`. 
Because `beautifulsoup` considers the attribute attrs of `title 'that i want'` like this: `{'class': ['td', 'p1']}.<br>`

But not like this: `{'class': ['td p1']}`

Comment: Both `{'class': ['td', 'p1']}` and `{'class': ['td p1']}` work. What are your problems, exactly?

Comment: How use soup.find to find
`<h1 class = 'td p1'>
     title that i want
</h1> `

Comment: Because When I do soup.find_all (class = 'td').
Beautifusoup finds:
`<h1 class = 'td p1'>
     title that i want
</h1>
<h1 class = 'td p2'>
     title that i don't want
</h1>`
And when I do soup.find_all (class = 'p1').
Beautifusoup finds:
`<h1 class = 'td p1'>
     title that i want
</h1>
<h1 class = 'p1'>
     title that i don't want
</h1>`

Comment: See the answer below. Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: I put a more generic case.
But I have the impression that in my personal case it works.
I did not know that we could put spaces.
So yes it works.
Maybe my problem comes from somewhere else.
So i will close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note** *Different approaches but both have in common to select the classes explicitly.*

###### find()

```
soup.find('h1', attrs={'class':'td p1'})
```

###### select_one()

```
soup.select_one('h1.td.p1')
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data="""
<h1 class='td p1'>
    title that i want
</h1>
<h1 class='td p2'>
    title that i don't want
</h1>
<h1 class='p1'>
    title that i don't want
</h1>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,"html.parser")

title = soup.select_one('h1.td.p1')

print(title)
```

#### Output

```
<h1 class="td p1">
    title that i want
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
html = """<h1 class='td p1'>
    title that i want
</h1>
<h1 class='td p2'>
    title that i don't want
</h1>
<h1 class='p2'>
    title that i don't want
</h1>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
content = soup.find('h1', attrs={'class':'td p1'})
```

output:

```
>>> print(content)
<h1 class="td p1">
    title that i want
</h1>
```